# How to change x axis increments and plot using log(x) on the xaxis?

Tags: python, plotly

I would like to shorten my xaxis so my data will be more visible. However, I don't know how to accomplish this while leaving my xaxis as log(x).

[image]

Here is my code for the above image:

```
data = Data([
    Bar(
        y=[x/float(114767406) for x in yp_views],
        x=[x for x in yp_views],
        name='Relative Frequency')])


layout = Layout(xaxis=XAxis(type='log',title = "Number of Premium Highlight Views")
                ,yaxis=YAxis(title = "Frequency"))

fig = Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

Here is what I tried:

I tried solving this problem by using histogram and the xbins. However, this doesn't allow me the freedom of using a custom x and y axis to plot. I don't see a xbins property for bar charts. Is there another name for it?

Here is trying to plot using the range:

```
data = Data([
    Bar(
        y=[x/float(114767406) for x in yp_views],
        x=[x for x in yp_views],
        name='Relative Frequency')])

layout = Layout(xaxis=XAxis(type='log', range = [3000,10000], title = "Number of Premium Highlight Views")
                ,yaxis=YAxis(title = "Frequency"))

fig = Figure(data = data, layout = layout)
py.iplot(fig)
```

[image]

Comment: oops, sorry my mistake.  You need to use `log` within your range.  So if you replace your `range` with `range=[np.log10(3000), np.log10(10000)]`, it should work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `range=[min, max]` in your `xaxis` / `yaxix` to define your desired range.  For example, your `layout` would look like something like this:

```
layout = Layout(xaxis=XAxis(type='log', range=[np.log10(3000), np.log10(10000)],
                title = "Number of Premium Highlight Views"),
                yaxis=YAxis(title = "Frequency"))
```

Comment: I got NaNe+Infinity along the x axis. Please see above for the image.